# Prevent meshes from clipping into each other

Tags: mesh

There are two meshes that are clipping into each other.

[image]

I used the boolean modifier to subtract the cylinder from the wall object. How do I fix this problem?

**[.blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33511)**

Comment: If you could upload your blend file [here](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/) I could take a look at it. Also you can upload your image directly to the question. Or if you don't the file host [imgur](http://imgur.com/) is preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are referring to what can be seen in the image below, this is called z-fighting. It is when to surfaces overlap and are in the same 3d space. This is not physically possible in the real world.

[image]

---

To fix this you would have to get rid of one of the overlapping surfaces.

1. Select the object `Cube`
2. Select the faces that are overlapping.

[image]

3. Delete them, <kbd>x</kbd> -> *Faces*

---

**Final Result**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Comrade's answer is good. If you want to keep both meshes intact, there is an alternative way.

1. Select the `Cylinder.001` object
2. Scale the object by hitting <kbd>s</kbd>
3. Scale it down by an appropriate amount. You can try `.99` to start. Keep adding 9's until you see z-fighting happening again. If so, hit the backspace to erase the last digit.

Answer (score 1):

Other solution would be to join both objects (In object mode select both and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>)

Then go into edit mode, select all the vertices and do Remove Doubles.

[image]

[image]